# Trying to get value from PHP multi_query

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm stuck on this problem for a while now and looking for helpful suggestions.

```
$resultset = $connection->multi_query($sql);

pseudo:

IF $resultset > 0 (--> if the sql query returned at least one result) {
 // do something
}
```

now the problem is with the pseudo part, i have tried to the follows:

```
if($resultset > 0) // takes no effect
if($resultset->num_rows > 0) // Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

I have to use multi_query so mysqli_query/mysqli_fetch_array is not a solution

thanks for the hints....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: how should it be a duplicate when the post you referring to, doesn't even contain the expression "multi_query"? in fact it's a link collection of PHP. do you think it's helpful? the reason why someone comes here to ask a problem is not to get answers like "google it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
if($connection->multi_query($sql))
{
    //sample query taken from php manual, see link below
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $connection->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($connection->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($connection->next_result());

}
else
{
    //handle error
    echo mysqli_error ( $connection );
}
```

If you check out the documentation of multi query ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)), you will see that the function returns a `boolean`.

Source code also taken from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't care about the condition but executes straight away. thanks though

Comment: I updated the code to actually grab hold of the result. Maybe it works now as expected - that is if i didn't include some copy pasta error ;)

Answer (score 2):

`multi_query()` returns a boolean that indicates whether the first query was successful, it doesn't return a `mysqli_result` object.

You have to call the `store_result()` method to get the first result set.

```
$resultset = $connection->store_result();
```

To get subsequent result sets you use `more_results()` and `next_result()`.

See the examples in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: i tried it like this: if($resultset = $connection->store_result()) { do something }, but i didn't work either. maybe i'm missing sthing here?

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you, this is exactly what it says to do in the documentation. I generally recommend avoiding multi-query, it usually makes things more complicated.

Comment: thank you for your help Barmar, i accepted Matthias' answer.

Comment: "I generally recommend avoiding multi-query,". you are right on this point - i must use it for this app. thanks again!